# Prevent Facebook Flow from checking linked npm package

Tags: npm, flowtype

I have a React Native application with a linked dependency which lies in the same parent folder:

```
home /
    app / node_modules / [common_stuff]
    common_stuff / ...
```

In my `.flowconfig` I have these lines:

```
[ignore]
../.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/common_stuff/.*
```

When I run `flow` it gives me this error:

```
../common_stuff/node_modules/find-elm-dependencies/test/fixtures/malformed-elm-package-json/elm-package.json:
  1: {-{ malformed JSON }-}
  ^ Unexpected token -
```

How can I prevent it from following the symbolic link?

Note that if I delete the `common_stuff/node_modules` folder, it works. But obviously, this is not a solution.

EDIT: I experiment the same behavior with a brand new project done using `react-native init MyProject` and `yarn link common_stuff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this expression in `.flowconfig`:

```
.*/node_modules/.*/elm-package.json
```

I don't think I'll have issues since it is a file related to Elm, a different environment. Nonetheless, I find it disappointing not being able to select more precisely what to ignore.